# How can I improve performance of finding all files in a folder created at a certain date?

Tags: python, performance, scandir

There are 10,000 files in a folder. Few files are created on 2018-06-01, few on 2018-06-09, like that.

I need to find all files which are created on 2018-06-09. But it is taking to much time (almost 2 hours) to read each file and get the file creation date and then get the files which are created on 2018-06-09.

```
for file in os.scandir(Path):
    if file.is_file():
        file_ctime = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file)).strftime('%Y- %m- %d %H:%M:%S')
        if file_ctime[0:4] == '2018-06-09':
            # ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the most basic thing - why are you building a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) only to re-format it as string and then do a string comparison?

Then there is the whole point of using [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) over [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) - [`os.scandir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) returns a [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) which caches file stats through the [`os.DirEntry.stat()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry.stat) call.

In dependence of checks you need to perform, [`os.listdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.listdir) might even perform better if you expect to do a lot of filtering on the filename as then you won't need to build up a whole [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) just to discard it.

So, to optimize your loop, if you don't expect a lot of filtering on the name:

```
for entry in os.scandir(Path):
    if entry.is_file() and 1528495200 <= entry.stat().st_ctime < 1528581600:
        pass  # do whatever you need with it
```

If you do, then better stick with `os.listdir()` as:

```
import stat

for entry in os.listdir(Path):
    # do your filtering on the entry name first...
    path = os.path.join(Path, entry)  # build path to the listed entry...
    stats = os.stat(path)  # cache the file entry statistics
    if stat.S_ISREG(stats.st_mode) and 1528495200 <= stats.st_ctime < 1528581600:
        pass  # do whatever you need with it
```

If you want to be flexible with the timestamps, use [`datetime.datetime.timestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp) beforehand to get the POSIX timestamps and then you can compare them against what [`stat_result.st_ctime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat_result.st_ctime) returns directly without conversion.

However, even your original, non-optimized approach should be significantly faster than 2 hours for a mere 10k entries. I'd check the underlying filesystem, too, something seems wrong there.

Comment: i want to compare specific date with file timestamp, so that's why i reformatted the file timestamp into a variable and comparing with specific date. Any suggestion to compare the specific date with file timestamp date ?

Comment: @GowthamChinatalacheruvu - The above is comparing against a specific date (`2018-06-09`), it's the equivalent of your code. As I wrote, if you want to be flexible with timestamps just build your own timestamps from dates - `1528495200` is what you'll get if you issue `datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 9).timestamp()` while `1528581600` is what you'll get if you issue `datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 10).timestamp()`. Store them in variables (`min_ts` and `max_ts` for example) and use them in the conditional (i.e. `min_ts <= entry.stat().st_ctime < max_ts`) and you get your flexibility.

Comment: when i use stat().st_ctime we will get the timestamp(date+time). When i am comparing this value with my specific date, which will fail. Any solution to get only date from st_ctime?

Comment: @GowthamChinatalacheruvu - Which is the reason why I am using a range above (from one timestamp to another) capturing the whole date span of `2018-06-09` - from `2018-06-09 00:00:00` to `2018-06-09 23:59:59`. I don't see why you need to convert it into a date just to do the comparison? If you want to get the date you can use [`datetime.date.fromtimestamp()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromtimestamp) but that will needlessly increase execution time of your code which you are trying to avoid based on your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using `os.listdir(path)` to get all the files and dirs from the given path.

Once you have all the files and directories you could use `filter` and a lambda function to create a new list of only the files with the desired timestamp.

You could then iterate through that list to do what work you need to on the correct files.